How to get the GtkWindow from G_DEFINE_TYPE declaration
I need to get the GtkWindow or toplevel widget from my G_DEFINE_TYPE:
MyAppWindow.c:
#include "MyAppWindow.h"

struct _MyAppWindow
{
    GtkApplicationWindow parent;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (MyAppWindow, my_app_window, GTK_TYPE_APPLICATION_WINDOW);

void my_app_window_init (MyAppWindow *app)
{
}

void my_app_window_class_init (MyAppWindowClass *class)
{
}

MyAppWindow * my_app_window_new (MyApp *app)
{
    return g_object_new (MY_APP_WINDOW_TYPE, "application", app, NULL);
}

MyAppWindow.h:
#ifndef _MY_APP_WINDOW_H_INCLUDED
#define _MY_APP_WINDOW_H_INCLUDED

#include "MyApp.h"

#define MY_APP_WINDOW_TYPE (my_app_window_get_type ())
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (MyAppWindow, my_app_window, MY, APP_WINDOW, GtkApplicationWindow)

MyAppWindow * my_app_window_new (MyApp *);

#endif

MyApp.c:
struct _MyApp
{
    GtkApplication parent;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (MyApp, my_app, GTK_TYPE_APPLICATION);

void my_app_init (MyApp *app)
{
}

void my_app_activate (GApplication *app)
{
    MyAppWindow *win;

// create window:
    win = my_app_window_new (MY_APP (app));
}

void my_app_class_init (MyAppClass *class)
{
    G_APPLICATION_CLASS (class)->activate = my_app_activate;
}

MyApp *my_app_new (AppData *pad)
{
    MyApp *obj = g_object_new (MY_APP_TYPE, "application-id", PROJECT_APPID, "flags", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS, NULL);
    return obj;
}

In my activate prototype:
void my_app_activate (GApplication *app)
{
     MyAppWindow *win = my_app_window_new (MY_APP (app));
     // .. more code
     g_action_map_add_action_entries (G_ACTION_MAP (app), entries, G_N_ELEMENTS (entries), app);
}

In some callback:
void cb_showmsg (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data)
{
     // user_data: need here to access both GApplication and MyAppWindow
    // One solution from user Holger (see comments):
    GtkWindow* toplevel = gtk_application_get_active_window (user_data);
   // 
}

I need MyAppWindow to show or hide the toplevel window, any ideas?

Can you please deliver MyApp.c?

Ok. I just Added it.

Maybe this feature can help.  gtk_application_get_active_window

If I use gtk_application_get_active_window  from a dialog, wouldn't be that dialog the active window and not my toplevel?

If the dialog was called by the top-level window, you can easily give it to the call.

Using gtk_application_get_active_window is one solution.

Since you pass app as the last argument for g_action_map_add_action_entries(), you can access the same in cb_showmsg() user_data. And to access the window, you can either keep track of the created MyAppWindow (ie, store it to some variable in the MyApp struct) or iterate over all available windows (with gtk_application_get_windows() and get the one we want.
So you can do something like this:
void cb_showmsg (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWindow *window = NULL;
  MyApp *app = user_data;
  GList *windows;

  g_assert (MY_IS_APP (app));

  /* Get MyAppWindow. If there are many, we get the most recently focused one */
  windows = gtk_application_get_windows (G_APPLICATION (app));
  for (GList *w = windows; w->data; w = w->next)
    {
      if (MY_IS_APP_WINDOW (w->data))
        {
          window = w->data;
          break;
        }
    }

  /* now do something with window */
  if (window)
    do_something ();
}


For now, seems that store GtkWindow in MyApp struct is the proper solution/workaround.
