g_object_bind_property with G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL freezes UI with strings, not with numbers
I'm attempting to update a GtkColumnView row from a custom dialog. Important code below:
cell_item.c:
#include "CellItem.h"

struct _CellItem
{
    GObject parent_instance;
    char *name;
    char *carrera;
    int grado;
};

struct _CellItemClass
{
    GObjectClass parent_class;
};

enum {
    PROP_NAME = 1,
    PROP_CARRER = 2,
    PROP_GRADE = 3,
    N_PROPERTIES
};

GParamSpec *obj_properties[N_PROPERTIES] = { NULL, };

G_DEFINE_TYPE (CellItem, cell_item, G_TYPE_OBJECT)

void cell_item_get_property (GObject *object, guint prop_id, GValue *value, GParamSpec *pspec)
{
    CellItem *self = CELL_ITEM (object);
    
    switch (prop_id)
    {
        case PROP_NAME:
            g_value_set_string (value, self->name);
            break;
        case PROP_CARRER:
            g_value_set_string (value, self->carrera);
            break;
        case PROP_GRADE:
            g_value_set_int (value, self->grado);
            break;
        default:
            G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID(object, prop_id, pspec);
    }
}

void cell_item_set_property (GObject *object, guint prop_id, const GValue *value, GParamSpec *pspec)
{
    CellItem *self = CELL_ITEM (object);

    switch (prop_id)
    {
        case PROP_NAME:
            g_free (self->name);
            self->name = g_value_dup_string (value);
            break;
        case PROP_CARRER:
            g_free (self->carrera);
            self->carrera = g_value_dup_string (value);
            break;
        case PROP_GRADE:
            self->grado = g_value_get_int (value);
            break;
        default:
            G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID (object, prop_id, pspec);
    }
}

void cell_item_init (CellItem *item)
{
    item->name = NULL;
    item->carrera = NULL;
    item->grado = 0;
}

void cell_item_class_init (CellItemClass *klass)
{
    GObjectClass *gobject_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS (klass);
    gobject_class->get_property = cell_item_get_property;
    gobject_class->set_property = cell_item_set_property;

    obj_properties[PROP_NAME] = g_param_spec_string ("name", NULL, NULL, NULL, G_PARAM_READWRITE);
    obj_properties[PROP_CARRER] = g_param_spec_string ("carrera", NULL, NULL, NULL, G_PARAM_READWRITE);
    obj_properties[PROP_GRADE] = g_param_spec_int ("grado", NULL, NULL, 0, 10, 0, G_PARAM_READWRITE);

    g_object_class_install_properties (gobject_class, N_PROPERTIES, obj_properties);
}

CellItem * cell_item_new (const char* nombre, const char* carrera, int grado)
{
    CellItem *item = g_object_new (CELL_ITEM_TYPE, NULL);
    item->name = g_strdup (nombre);
    item->carrera = g_strdup (carrera);
    item->grado = grado;
    return item;
}

const char* cell_item_get_name (CellItem* ci)
{
    return ci->name;
}

const char* cell_item_get_carrera (CellItem* ci)
{
    return ci->carrera;
}

int cell_item_get_grade (CellItem* ci)
{
    return ci->grado;
}

void cell_item_set_grade (CellItem* ci, int num)
{
    ci->grado = num;
}

void cell_item_set_name (CellItem* ci, const char* name)
{
    g_free (ci->name);
    ci->name = g_strdup (name);
}

void cell_item_set_carrera (CellItem* ci, const char* carrera)
{
    g_free (ci->carrera);
    ci->carrera = g_strdup (carrera);
}

MyApp.c:
void my_app_activate (GApplication *app)
{
    MyAppWindow *win;
    GtkWidget *child;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *hspacer;
    GtkWidget *scrolled_win;
    GtkWidget *view;
    GMenu *menu_model;
    GMenu *menu_sec1;
    GMenu *menu_sec2;
    GMenu *menu_sec3;
    GListStore *list_model;
    GtkColumnViewColumn* column;
    GtkListItemFactory *factory;
    GtkSingleSelection *selection;

// create window:
    win = my_app_window_new (MY_APP (app));
    GtkIconTheme *theme = gtk_icon_theme_get_for_display (gdk_display_get_default ());
    gtk_icon_theme_add_resource_path (theme, "/gtk4/aullidolunar/" PROGRAM_NAME);
    gtk_window_set_default_icon_name (PROGRAM_NAME);
    gtk_window_set_icon_name (GTK_WINDOW (win), PROGRAM_NAME);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), PROJECT_NAME_TITLE);

// action entries:
    const GActionEntry entries[] =
    {
        {"agrega", cb_addtoview, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 0, 0 }},
        {"edita", cb_edita, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 0, 0 }},
        {"muestra1", cb_showme1, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 0, 0 }},
        {"muestra2", cb_showme2, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 0, 0 }},
        {"salida", cb_quit, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 0, 0 }}
    };
    g_action_map_add_action_entries (G_ACTION_MAP (app), entries, G_N_ELEMENTS (entries), app);
    const gchar *agrega[] = {"<ctrl>a", NULL};
    const gchar *edita[] = {"<ctrl>e", NULL};
    const gchar *carga1[] = {"<ctrl>b", NULL};
    const gchar *carga2[] = {"<ctrl>d", NULL};
    const gchar *salida[] = {"<ctrl>s", "<ctrl>w", "<ctrl>q", NULL};
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (GTK_APPLICATION (app), "app.agrega", agrega);
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (GTK_APPLICATION (app), "app.edita", edita);
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (GTK_APPLICATION (app), "app.muestra1", carga1);
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (GTK_APPLICATION (app), "app.muestra2", carga2);
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (GTK_APPLICATION (app), "app.salida", salida);

// create child container:
    child = gtk_grid_new ();

// UI:
    menu_model = g_menu_new ();
    menu_sec1 = g_menu_new ();
    menu_sec2 = g_menu_new ();
    menu_sec3 = g_menu_new ();
    g_menu_append (menu_sec1, "_Agregar...", "app.agrega");
    g_menu_append (menu_sec1, "_Editar...", "app.edita");
    g_menu_append_section (menu_model, NULL, G_MENU_MODEL (menu_sec1));
    g_menu_append (menu_sec2, "_Mostrar 1", "app.muestra1");
    g_menu_append (menu_sec2, "_Mostrar 2", "app.muestra2");
    g_menu_append_section (menu_model, NULL, G_MENU_MODEL (menu_sec2));
    g_menu_append (menu_sec3, "_Salir", "app.salida");
    g_menu_append_section (menu_model, NULL, G_MENU_MODEL (menu_sec3));
    
    button = gtk_menu_button_new ();
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand (button, FALSE);
    gtk_menu_button_set_icon_name (GTK_MENU_BUTTON (button), "action_ui");
    gtk_menu_button_set_menu_model (GTK_MENU_BUTTON (button), G_MENU_MODEL (menu_model));
    
    hspacer = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand (hspacer, TRUE);
    
    scrolled_win = gtk_scrolled_window_new ();
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_win), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    
    list_model = g_list_store_new (G_TYPE_OBJECT);
    selection = gtk_single_selection_new (G_LIST_MODEL (list_model));
    MY_APP (app)->data->view = gtk_column_view_new (GTK_SELECTION_MODEL (selection));
    //gtk_column_view_set_single_click_activate (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (view), FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand (MY_APP (app)->data->view, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand (MY_APP (app)->data->view, TRUE);
    const char *column_names[] = { "Nombre", "Carrera", "Grado", NULL };
    for (int i = 0; column_names[i]; i++)
    {
        factory = gtk_signal_list_item_factory_new ();
        g_signal_connect (factory, "setup", G_CALLBACK (factory_setup), GINT_TO_POINTER (i));
        g_signal_connect (factory, "bind", G_CALLBACK (factory_bind), GINT_TO_POINTER (i));
        column = gtk_column_view_column_new (column_names[i], factory);
        gtk_column_view_append_column (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (MY_APP (app)->data->view), column);
    }
// testing the model:
    g_list_store_append (list_model, cell_item_new ("Joel", "Ciencias de la Comunicación", 10));
    g_list_store_append (list_model, cell_item_new ("Foo", "Cinematografía", 7));
    g_list_store_append (list_model, cell_item_new ("Bar", "Derecho", 25));
    g_list_store_append (list_model, cell_item_new ("Buz", "Diseño de Modas", -5));
    
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_child (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_win), MY_APP (app)->data->view);

// layout:
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (child), button, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (child), hspacer, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (child), scrolled_win, 0, 1, 2, 1);
    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (win), child);

// Associate the toplevel to our GApplication:
    MY_APP (app)->win = GTK_WINDOW (win);

// test the association:
    gtk_window_present (MY_APP (app)->win);

// clean up:
    g_object_unref (menu_sec3);
    g_object_unref (menu_sec2);
    g_object_unref (menu_sec1);
    g_object_unref (menu_model);
    g_object_unref (theme);
}

callbacks.c:
#include "callbacks.h"

void cb_ok_clicked (GtkButton* self, gpointer user_data)
{
    MyDialogInfo *di_ptr = user_data;
    di_ptr->response = GTK_RESPONSE_OK;
    g_main_loop_quit (di_ptr->loop);
}

void cb_cancel_clicked (GtkButton* self, gpointer user_data)
{
    MyDialogInfo *di_ptr = user_data;
    di_ptr->response = GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL;
    g_main_loop_quit (di_ptr->loop);
}

gboolean cb_dlg_close_request (GtkWindow* self, gpointer user_data)
{
    MyDialogInfo *di_ptr = user_data;
    g_main_loop_quit (di_ptr->loop);
    return FALSE;
}

// add more rows
void cb_addtoview (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data)
{
// get the toplevel window associated to our GApplication
    GtkWindow* toplevel = my_app_get_toplevel (user_data);
    MyDialogInfo di = {0};
    input_dialog_show (toplevel, "Información del usuario", &di);
    if (di.response == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
    {
        AppData *ad_ptr = my_app_get_data (user_data);
        GtkSelectionModel* selection = gtk_column_view_get_model (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (ad_ptr->view));
        GListModel* model = gtk_single_selection_get_model (GTK_SINGLE_SELECTION (selection));
        CellItem *new_item = cell_item_new (di.nombre, di.carrera, di.grade);
        g_list_store_append (G_LIST_STORE (model), new_item);
// clean up:
        g_object_unref (new_item);
        g_free (di.nombre);
        g_free (di.carrera);
    }
}

// edit/update data from selected row
void cb_edita (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data)
{
    AppData *app = my_app_get_data (user_data);
    GtkWidget *view = app->view;
    GtkSelectionModel *model = gtk_column_view_get_model (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (view));
// get current row selected
    CellItem *sel_row = gtk_single_selection_get_selected_item (GTK_SINGLE_SELECTION (model));
    if (sel_row)
    {
        GtkWindow* toplevel = gtk_application_get_active_window (user_data);
        MyDialogInfo di = {0};
        input_dialog_show (toplevel, "Información del usuario", &di);
        if (di.response == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
        {
// fixme:
// The below code, "grado" is the only one with live update if I remove G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL from "name" and "carrera".
// G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL in name and carrera freeze the UI. :(
            g_object_set (sel_row, "name", di.nombre, "carrera", di.carrera, "grado", di.grade, NULL);
            g_free (di.nombre);
            g_free (di.carrera);
        }
    }
}

// show the name and grade information based on a row number
void cb_showme1 (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data)
{
// get my data from user_data
    AppData* app = my_app_get_data (user_data);
    GtkWindow* toplevel = my_app_get_toplevel (user_data);
    GtkWidget *view = app->view;
    GtkSelectionModel* model = gtk_column_view_get_model (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (view));
// helped by: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gtk4-finding-a-row-data-on-gtkcolumnview/8465/2
    int n = g_list_model_get_n_items (G_LIST_MODEL (model));
    g_print ("Total rows: %d\n", n); // for example: 4
// fun part:
    int n_row = 1; // I choose row 1
// In gtktest-2.4, will test if n_row is a valid row position
// select row[n_row]:
    GObject *row = g_list_model_get_object (G_LIST_MODEL (model), n_row);
    output_dialog_show (toplevel, "Mostrar información seleccionada", n_row, CELL_ITEM (row));
// clean up:
    g_object_unref (row);
}

void cb_showme2 (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data)
{
    AppData *app = my_app_get_data (user_data);
    GtkWidget *view = app->view;
// helped by: https://blog.gtk.org/2020/09/08/on-list-models/
    GtkSelectionModel *model = gtk_column_view_get_model (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (view));
// get current zero-based position of the current row selected
    int selected_index = gtk_single_selection_get_selected (GTK_SINGLE_SELECTION (model));
    if (selected_index != GTK_INVALID_LIST_POSITION)
    {
// Idea from https://stackoverflow.com/q/78578841/2030219
        GtkWindow* toplevel = gtk_application_get_active_window (user_data);
        //g_print ("Selected row index: %i\n", selected_index);
// You can use this one:
//      GObject *row = g_list_model_get_object (G_LIST_MODEL (model), selected_index);
// or:
        GObject *row = gtk_single_selection_get_selected_item (GTK_SINGLE_SELECTION (model));
        output_dialog_show (toplevel, "Mostrar información seleccionada", selected_index, CELL_ITEM (row));
    }
    else
    {
        g_print ("Nothing is selected\n");
    }
}

void cb_quit (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data)
{
    g_application_quit (G_APPLICATION (user_data));
}

void cb_gesture_pressed (GtkGestureClick* self, gint n_press, gdouble x, gdouble y, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (n_press == 2)
    {
        gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (user_data), TRUE);
        gtk_widget_grab_focus (GTK_WIDGET (user_data));
    }
    else
    {
        gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (user_data), FALSE);
    }
}

void factory_setup (GtkListItemFactory *factory, GtkListItem *list_item, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *widget_item;
    int i = GPOINTER_TO_INT (user_data);
    //GObject *item = gtk_list_item_get_item (list_item);
    
    if (i != ID_GRADE)
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/77180065/2030219
        widget_item = gtk_editable_label_new ("");
        gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (widget_item), FALSE);
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/78560182/2030219 &&
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/76614510/2030219
        GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
        g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (cb_gesture_pressed), widget_item);
        gtk_widget_add_controller (widget_item, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
    }
    else
    {
        widget_item = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range (0, 10, 1);
        gtk_spin_button_set_wrap (GTK_SPIN_BUTTON (widget_item), TRUE);
    }
    
    gtk_list_item_set_child (list_item, widget_item);
}

void factory_bind (GtkListItemFactory *factory, GtkListItem *list_item, gpointer user_data)
{
    int i = GPOINTER_TO_INT (user_data);
    GtkWidget *widget_item;

    widget_item = gtk_list_item_get_child (list_item);
    GObject *item = gtk_list_item_get_item (list_item);
    
    switch (i)
    {
        case ID_NAME:
            gtk_editable_set_text (GTK_EDITABLE (widget_item), cell_item_get_name (CELL_ITEM (item)));
// this way we get the live update change in GtkColumnView from cb_edita
            g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "name", widget_item, "text", G_BINDING_SYNC_CREATE);
            break;
        case ID_CARRER:
            gtk_editable_set_text (GTK_EDITABLE (widget_item), cell_item_get_carrera (CELL_ITEM (item)));
            g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "carrera", widget_item, "text", G_BINDING_SYNC_CREATE);
            break;
        case ID_GRADE:
            gtk_spin_button_set_value (GTK_SPIN_BUTTON (widget_item), cell_item_get_grade (CELL_ITEM (item)));
            g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "grado", widget_item, "value", G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL);
            break;
    }
}

Any ideas why the toplevel window freezes with G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL in strings but not with numbers?
Update 06/15/2024:
There's a loop in g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "name", widget_item, "text", G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL); that causes Notify::text triggered on each key press updateing my "name" on each notification and then send it back to editable... and so on like a ping-pong effect. Searching around I found a workaround solution that helps in two part process.
First, in bind callback we stick to G_BINDING_SYNC_CREATE:
void factory_bind (GtkListItemFactory *factory, GtkListItem *list_item, gpointer user_data)
{
    int i = GPOINTER_TO_INT (user_data);
    GtkWidget *widget_item;

    widget_item = gtk_list_item_get_child (list_item);
    GObject *item = gtk_list_item_get_item (list_item);
    
    switch (i)
    {
        case ID_NAME:
            gtk_editable_set_text (GTK_EDITABLE (widget_item), cell_item_get_name (CELL_ITEM (item)));
// For now, we don't use:
//          g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "name", widget_item, "text", G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL);
// to avoid the "ping-pong" loop between "name" and "text". Every single keypress in widget_item triggers notify::text
            g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "name", widget_item, "text", G_BINDING_SYNC_CREATE);
            break;
        case ID_CARRER:
            gtk_drop_down_set_selected (GTK_DROP_DOWN (widget_item), cell_item_get_carrera (CELL_ITEM (item)));
            g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "carrera", widget_item, "selected", G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL);
            break;
        case ID_GRADE:
            gtk_spin_button_set_value (GTK_SPIN_BUTTON (widget_item), cell_item_get_grade (CELL_ITEM (item)));
            g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "grado", widget_item, "value", G_BINDING_BIDIRECTIONAL);
            break;
    }
}

Second, in setup callback connect to has-focus to get notification when user finishes editing:
void factory_setup (GtkListItemFactory *factory, GtkListItem *list_item, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *widget_item;
    int i = GPOINTER_TO_INT (user_data);
    
    switch (i)
    {
        case ID_NAME:
            //https://stackoverflow.com/a/77180065/2030219
            widget_item = gtk_editable_label_new ("");
            gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (widget_item), FALSE);
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/78560182/2030219 &&
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/76614510/2030219
            GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
            g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (cb_gesture_pressed), widget_item);
            gtk_widget_add_controller (widget_item, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
// Idea from https://discourse.gnome.org/t/signal-after-finishing-entry-editing/14739/3:
// connect to has-focus for detect when the user hits "Enter" or "Return" key in the editable field
// See section "Notify signal" in https://github.com/ToshioCP/Gobject-tutorial/blob/main/gfm/sec5.md#notify-signal
            g_signal_connect (widget_item, "notify::has-focus", G_CALLBACK (on_editable_done_editing1), list_item);
            break;
        case ID_CARRER:
            widget_item = gtk_drop_down_new_from_strings (load_carreras_string ());
            break;
        case ID_GRADE:
            widget_item = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range (0, 10, 1);
            gtk_spin_button_set_wrap (GTK_SPIN_BUTTON (widget_item), TRUE);
            break;
    }
    
    gtk_list_item_set_child (list_item, widget_item);
}

the on_editable_done_editing1 callback code:
void on_editable_done_editing1 (GObject* self, GParamSpec* pspec, gpointer user_data)
{
    
    gboolean editing_mode = gtk_editable_label_get_editing (GTK_EDITABLE_LABEL (self));
    gboolean editable_has_focus = gtk_widget_has_focus (GTK_WIDGET (self));
    
// Done editing and no more focus in theory the user "entered" some string, but...
// fixme: also means "Escape" was hitted, keeping the same string
    if (!editing_mode && !editable_has_focus)
    {
// Fixme: don't store the data if user didn't change the editable string:
        const gchar* new_text = gtk_editable_get_text (GTK_EDITABLE (self));
        CellItem *item = gtk_list_item_get_item (user_data);
// According to ToshioCP/Gobject-tutorial, the "new" string is stored in the list model and no signal/notification is emitted in
// g_object_bind_property (CELL_ITEM (item), "name", widget_item, "text", G_BINDING_SYNC_CREATE);
// so, in theory, this won't create the ping-pong effect:
        cell_item_set_name (item, new_text);
// now, go and see if "new_text" is the updated name of the user («Ctrl+d» in the current selected row)
        g_print ("Editable: [%s], cell_item_name: [%s].\n", new_text, cell_item_get_name (item));
    }

}

So at this point no freeze UI and the data is stored as expected. Only thing left is not to store data if the user didn't change anything from the editable. I guess that would be something like compare old string with the new one.

I assume you have good reasons for just publishing parts of your program here. And of course I respect that.  However, the parts provided are not sufficient to get the program to run with reasonable effort.  Because as already said, the error seems to be in the concept rather than in de Syntax. Sorry. Greetings

That's basically the important part of the program, left behind parts irrelevant like the toplevel creation and the input/out dialog creation. I understand that this code doesn't "compile, run and test", but I appreciate your tips and suggestions. Also greetings, my friend.

It would be a lot of effort to recreate the programme.  So I can only assume that there is an infinite loop here, which then leads to a freeze of the screen.
That this only happens with the stings and not at the value is probably due to the fact that the "EditableLabel" and "SpinButton" send the signal "GObject::notify" differently. However, since this signal has an important trigger function for syncronisation, this different result also occurs.
Without knowing the whole program, I cannot give an exhaustive answer :-(.  Especially since the problem here does not seem to lie in a syntay error, but rather in the concept. Two automatisms are mixed with the factory principle and G-BINDING-BIDIRECTIONAL.Since these are then not syncronized and cannot become, the result is undefined.
In my imagination, a change should always be confirmed by the user. This can be done by a button or by "Enter".
How to determine the content of a selected item is shown in this example. ListView editable, with GTK4, C and VFL
How "Enter" or "TAB" can determine is shown in this example.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78558511/22768315
There may also be a solution in the documentation:
" The loop, in this particular case, can be avoided if the objects emit the GObject::notify signal only if the value has effectively been changed. A binding is implemented using the GObject::notify signal, so it is susceptible to all the various ways of blocking a signal emission, like g_signal_stop_emission() or g_signal_handler_block()."
Source: https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/class.Binding.html
For a complete solution, please deliver the full program.
Nice that someone has just as much fun programming with GTK4 and C as I do.

OK. As another attempt: Os there a way we can get the widgets items of the selected row? For example, get the first widget, the gtk_editable_label for "nombre", and change the text from my custom function cb_edita.

Yes, you were right about the infinite loop.
